# Replace single character in fasta header with awk or sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed, bioinformatics, fasta

I am working in bash with a fasta file with headers that begin with a ">" and end with either a "C" or a "+". Like so:

```
>chr1:35031657-35037706+
GGTGGACTAGCCAGTGAATGTCAACGCGTCCCTA
CCTAAGGCGATATCCGCAGCCGCCCGCGTCCCTA
>chr1:71979382-71985425C
agattaaatgaactattacacataaagtgcttac
ttacacataaagtgcttacgaactattacaggga
```

I'd like to use awk (gsub?) or sed to change the last character of the header to a "+" if it is a "C". Basically I want all of the sequences to end in "+". No C's.

Desired output:

```
>chr1:35031657-35037706+
GGTGGACTAGCCAGTGAATGTCAACGCGTCCCTA
CCTAAGGCGATATCCGCAGCCGCCCGCGTCCCTA
>chr1:71979382-71985425+
agattaaatgaactattacacataaagtgcttac
ttacacataaagtgcttacgaactattacaggga
```

Nothing needs to change with the sequences. I think this is pretty straight forward, but I'm struggling to use other posts to do this myself. I know that `awk '/^>/ && /C$/{print $0}'` will print the headers than begin with ">" and end with "C", but I'm not sure how to replace all of those "C"s with "+"s.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this would be easier to do in `sed`:

```
sed '/^>/ s/C$/+/'
```

Translation: on lines starting with ">", replace "C" at the end of the line with "+". Note that if the "C" isn't matched, there isn't an error, it just doesn't replace anything. Also, unlike `awk`, `sed` automatically prints each line after processing it.

If you really want to use `awk`, the equivalent would be:

```
awk '/^>/ {sub("C$","+",$0)}; {print}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -pe 's{^(>.*)C$}{$1+}' input.fasta > output.fasta
```

Or, to change the file in-place:

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's{^(>.*)C$}{$1+}' input.fasta
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.
`-i.bak` : Edit input files in-place (overwrite the input file). Before overwriting, save a backup copy of the original file by appending to its name the extension `.bak`. If you want to skip writing a backup file, just use `-i` and skip the extension.

`s{^(>.*)C$}{$1+}` : Change the line that starts with `>` (= fasta header) and ends with `C` to the same line with `C` changed to `+`.
`^` marks the beginning of the line and `$` marks the end of the line. `.*` means any character repeated 0 or more times. `(>.*)` captures the pattern inside, which is the entire line minus the `C`, and stores it in capture variable `$1`.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes): Quantifiers; Character Classes and other Special Escapes; Assertions; Capture groups](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions)
[`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)

Answer (score 0):

You might harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
>chr1:35031657-35037706+
GGTGGACTAGCCAGTGAATGTCAACGCGTCCCTA
CCTAAGGCGATATCCGCAGCCGCCCGCGTCCCTA
>chr1:71979382-71985425C
agattaaatgaactattacacataaagtgcttac
ttacacataaagtgcttacgaactattacaggga
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT=".";OFS=""}$1==">"{$NF="+"}{print}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
>chr1:35031657-35037706+
GGTGGACTAGCCAGTGAATGTCAACGCGTCCCTA
CCTAAGGCGATATCCGCAGCCGCCCGCGTCCCTA
>chr1:71979382-71985425+
agattaaatgaactattacacataaagtgcttac
ttacacataaagtgcttacgaactattacaggga
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that field is any single character using `FPAT` and output field separator is empty string using `OFS`. For each line where 1st field, that is 1st character is `>` I change value of last field (`$NF`) to `+`. Note this is applied also to headers ending with `+` but this is not problem as it changes `+` to `+`. Each line, changed or not, is `print`ed.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*